# baked normals dont fill uvs

Tags: uv, baking, normal-map

[image]

I am having trouble with baking normals on these pants i modeled. you can see in the image that the top right. The normal just ends in the middle of the uvs. does anyone know of a way to deal with this sort of things? I had a high poly pair of pants with the folds and details and then retopologied using the snap to face toggle. so the models are the same shape and size.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was to do with the Ray Distance setting. I dont know how it works exactly but it happened to the parts of the leg that were facing each other and sitting close to each other. turning the ray distance down to .1 instead of 1 made the normal render perfect.